# Use https in spark-java

Tags: spark-java

How can i use custom SSLContext and custom SSLServerSocketFactory in spark-java framework?
I've searched in SparkServerImpl but have no idea how to inject sslfactory, any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass directly into Spark the parameters of the keystore, like this:

```
Spark.secure(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword, trustStorePath, trustStorePassword);
```

Those are all strings, and for example, the keystore values could be:

```
String keyStorePath = "/home/user/keys/private-key.jks";
String keyStorePassword = "password";
```

This way, Spark will have the parameters to create the SslContextFactory inside, as you can see here:

https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/2.3/src/main/java/spark/webserver/jetty/SocketConnectorFactory.java#L68-L82